# regex for google outbound link forward pattern

Tags: regex, url

i'm trying to filter a number of exported google docs from google outbound forwarding links. any url inserted as link into the doc is redirected via

```
https://www.google.com/url?q=
```

with additional nasty tracking features appended to that url

```
&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1460132191131000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHtElMgAbdJQw__--jthRvFeSsWtQ
```

thus, a complete url would look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.url.com/folder/&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1460132191131000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHtElMgAbdJQw__--jthRvFeSsWtQ
```

figuring out the regular expression to filter these, only leaving the actual url part, unfortunately is beyond my means.

Comment: Can you tell what part of the url you want to extract? Target output I mean.

Comment: sure – the actual url, in this case http://www.url.com/folder/ – but the regex needs to extract any url in between ?q= and &amp;sa=

Comment: @CPanda The OP did say *... filter these, only leaving the **actual url part**, unfortunately is ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple Method

If your URL is ***exactly as shown in the question*** (`https`, `google.com`, `etc.`), use the following RegEx:

```
https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/url\?q=([^&]*)
```

The data will be stored in the **`1st` Capture Group** - <kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/fH7uJ4/1)</kbd>

You can also remove the brackets, and use `\K` to reset the RegEx, then the URL will be the whole match (no capture groups needed):

```
https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/url\?q=\K[^&]*
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/sM7nD7/1)</kbd>

---

### Safer Method

If your RegEx is not exactly as shown (maybe `http`, `google.co.uk`, `etc.`), try this one, it is safer:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?google(\.\w{1,3})+\/url\?(.*?)q=([^&]*)
```

The URL will be stored in the **`5th` Capture Group** - <kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/nO4bB1/3)</kbd>

How it works:

```
^          # String starts with ...
(          # http(s)://
  http       # http
  s?         # Optional s (for https)
  :\/\/      # ://
)?         # HTTP(S) Protocol is optional (for just www.google....)
(www\.)?   # Optional www. (for just http://google....)
google     # google
(          # TLD(s) - .com, .co.uk, .com.vn
  \.         # .
  \w{1,3}    # TLD between 1 and 3 letters
)+         # Multiple TLDs
\/url      # /url
\?         # ?
(.*?)      # Optional other params before q=
q=         # q=
(          # Capture URL
  [^&]*      # Any character until an & sign. repeated as many times as possible
)
```

---

Alternatively, use `\K` and non-capturing groups - `(?:...)`:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?google(?:\.\w{1,3})+\/url\?(?:.*?)q=\K([^&]*)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kZ1dT8/2)</kbd>

---

For the Find and Replace in **Notepad++**, use the safer RegEx (with capturing groups), and `.*` on the end:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?google(\.\w{1,3})+\/url\?(.*?)q=([^&]*).*
```

And replace with `$5` (the `5th` Capturing Group).

Set up the Find and Replace like so (make sure `.` **does not** match newline):

[image: Find and Replace Settings]

Then press *Replace All*. It will replace all the matches.

Alternatively, use the *Find Next* and *Replace* buttons to loop through them individually:

[image: Using *Find Next* and *Replace* button to Find and Replace each match individually]

Comment: cheers for that! how could i use this within the context of a text editor (like smultron) that allows for regex search & replace – i'm looking to search for these urls, and then strip away the google redirect bits in the beginning and end (the first part is simple, never changes)

Comment: @jodldoe I can tell you how to do it for Notepad++? I do not have smultron.

Comment: sure that'd be fine as well!

Comment: @jodldoe No, it will not. Copy the RegEx I put in the section on how to Find and Replace. Basically, you just add `.*` to the end.

Comment: got it now, thanks! when i use this in an html document with a href links, it will also remove the last part of the link syntax `">` – any way the regexp could be specified so that this part would remain?

Comment: @jodldoe Yup. Just replace the `.*` with `[^"]*`, it will select any character except a `"`.

Comment: @jodldoe No Problem!